# What happens when @version exceeds int limit?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I am using `@Version` for concurrency management in spring boot entity. My question is what happens when `@version` column exceeds integer / long limit. Will it reset itself?

I am trying to achieve concurrency during simultaneous update calls in a multi-threaded application

Comment: The value will wrap around (i.e. after `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the next value will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, similar for long) but this shouldn't be a problem because update statements contain `UPDATE xy SET version=?, ... WHERE id=? and version=?` - i.e. it is always only a test for an identical value, it is never a greater/equals or less/equals.

Comment: In other words: it's *only* a problem if it wraps all the way back around between the last read and an attempted update of one process.